# What variables do I need to create a line of any shape?

Tags: functions

If I have a chart and I want to be able to draw a line of any shape, what formula and variables do I need?

The only constraint is that the line will never go back on itself.

To clarify the above statement. Every x value will only have one corresponding y value and every y value will only have one x value (With the possible exception of a straight horizontal line), the lines will always be smooth and continuous.

I'm lacking the mathematical vocabulary to explain myself clearly, so please ask for clarification if required and suggest more appropriate tags.

Something like:

```
y = x * multiplier ^ n + offset
```

Examples of the kinds of lines I'd like to be able to create are

[image]

Comment: if you have a chart, you have a set of points. Sounds like you are looking to obtain a formula that will produce a line that goes thru every point in the data set. This is called interpolation and there are many ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

**This question is too broad to be answered**, but I will give you some advice.

A line that doesn't "go back in on itself" can mean many things.  Let's presume that you mean you want to create only **functions**, these are much more restricted curves that not only do not intersect themselves but also always have one y value for a given x value.

Let's now make a **huge** assumption: that you also want to draw functions that are "continuous".  Intuitively, a function is continuous if you can draw it without ever lifting your pen off of the paper.   It has no "holes", and it does not look like a staircase (that is, it has no "jumps" either).

Finally, let's assume that the functions are also defined only on a small portion of the x-axis.  "small" can take on a loose meaning - as long as it is not defined on the entire x axis, or at least as long as you are only interested in a portion of the entire function, rather than the whole thing.

This isn't really strict enough to be able to give a good answer, since there are many continuous functions that cannot be described with the method I'm about to show you.  However, the method below is pretty decent for a large number of functions.

You can use a polynomial to approximate many continuous functions.  These look like this:

$$y = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1x + a_0 $$

The higher the order polynomial you want, the more accurately you can represent functions that are not polynomials themselves.

So to answer your question, using polynomials, you need:

1. An order, $n$, which you might want to treat as a variable when you are choosing it
2. x and y
3. All of the coefficients, $a_i$, which are just real, constant numbers

This method is limited - a huge thing it can't do is describe functions that are not continuous.  To find a truly universal method of drawing curves exactly is probably impossible, so you will need to restrict your definition before you can make better progress.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. You've helped me clarify my thinking too. Every x value will only have one corresponding y value, the lines will always be smooth, continuous and will never reverse its direction.